# Authorization in jersey framework

Tags: jersey, authorization

I am using jersey (java) framework. I did authentication based on cookie using Container request filter. Now I have to do Authorization. So, how to I proceed? Quick guidance please.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey has `@RolesAllowed("role")` annotation to facilitate auth check. Make use of:

```java
@Context
HttpServletRequest httpRequest;`
```

and in the login method put identity into session like here:

```java
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute(key, val);
```

in filter

```java
final String name = session.getAttribute(key);

...

SecurityContext securityContext = new SecurityContext() {

    public boolean isUserInRole(String roleName) {
        return roleName.equals("role");
    }

...

    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {

        ...

        return new Principal() {
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
        };

        ...

    }

...

};

requestContext.setSecurityContext(securityContext);
```

That's it in short. It is quite common approach. If you want I can share ref impl on GitHub.

Comment: Sorry, it was wrong project. Now I pushed the proper one.